# position: fixed behaving like position: absolute

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

This fiddle demonstrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/nh7q9be4/

Blue translucent div has `position` set to `fixed`, but it is being positioned relative to the red div. How do I position it relative to the viewport?

Comment: left:0 top:0 ? ...

Comment: 1st no need to add `height:100%` on body or html. 2nd your `.a` height = `body` height. So you wont ever see the bottom of it this way, what you should do is set `.a { height: 100vh; }`. So what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Temani Afif This is the answer.